# Angular : Bindinig form and Ui grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a form that save information from user and show it in grid (form is bind to grid). i got a problem that when user save another inormation , old values changed, but after refresh it will be okay . here is my code :

```
   $scope.requestAuthorization = {};
    $scope.requestAuthorizationList = [];
$scope.GetRequestAuthorizationbyRequestCode = function (id) {

        BaseService.getDataByParameter(urlBase + 'GetRequestAuthorizationbyRequestCode', id).success(function (data) {
            debugger
            $scope.requestAuthorizationList = data;
            $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.requestAuthorizationList;

        })
    }

    $scope.SaveRequestAuthorization = function () {
        debugger;
        if (checkDate()) {
            $scope.requestAuthorization.RequestCode = requestCode;
            $scope.requestAuthorization.cityCode = cityCode;
            $scope.requestAuthorization.RgnCode = regionCode;

            BaseService.save(urlBase + 'SaveRequestAuthorization', $scope.requestAuthorization).success(function () {
                debugger;

                        $scope.requestAuthorizationList.push($scope.requestAuthorization);

            })
                //.error(function () {
                //    $scope.requestAuthorization.authorizationIssueDate = issueDate;
                //    $scope.requestAuthorization.authorizationExpDate = expDate;
                //});
        } else {

            toaster.pop('error', "تاریخ انتقضا نباید کوچکتر از تاریخ صدور باشد");

        }



    }
```

Register api  (grid):

```
onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
        $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
        gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope, function (row) {
            $scope.requestAuthorization = row.entity;
        });
    }
```

is there any solution that prevent to change data model in grid ?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating Model in Angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212088/updating-model-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

I thinks you should do operation on the original array rather than assign the data to a new value.
Please put more code so i point the incorrect place.

I guess you update gridOptions.data with a new value instead of do operation based on the original data.

Comment: i put the imoprtant part , the problem is user when insert new data is ok but if user want to insert new data with same model latest info will updated