# Updating Model in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Here is the plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/s9MwSbiZkbwBcPlHWMAq?p=preview

If I add information twice, latest data are the same, how can I prevent model from updating?

```
 $scope.personList = [];
  $scope.newPerson = {};
  $scope.columns = [{ field: 'Name' }, { field: 'Country' }];
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableSorting: true,
    columnDefs: $scope.columns,
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
  };

  $scope.addPerson = function(){

  $scope.personList.push($scope.newPerson);

}

  $http.get('file.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.personList = data.records; 
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data.records;
      console.log($scope.gridOptions.data);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copy using `angular.copy()` so you aren't pushing reference to the same object into the array each time.

```
$scope.addPerson = function(){
  var newPerson= angular.copy($scope.newPerson);
  $scope.newPerson ={}; // reset to clear view
  $scope.personList.push(newPerson);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are trying to do.

[Updated Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/re5fCDdVzEfV2WiPZqQM?p=preview)

**Change in JS**

```
$scope.addPerson = function(){

    $scope.personList.push(angular.copy($scope.newPerson)); //optional to use angular.copy()
    $scope.newPerson={}; //reset the object rather than one field
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is, you need to check the index of the item in the list before pushing into it. If the index > -1 then push.

```
$scope.addPerson = function(){

  if($scope.personList.indexOf($scope.newPerson > -1){
    $scope.personList.push($scope.newPerson);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a plunker with the [solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/afNDlgwkDUFez8tSRptS?p=preview):

You should add this function :

```
$scope.containsObject= function(obj, list) {
var i;
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i] === obj) {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

}

which will be called inside

```
  $scope.addPerson = function(){

if (!$scope.containsObject($scope.newPerson, $scope.personList)) {

  $scope.personList.push($scope.newPerson);
 $scope.newPerson.Name = '';
 }
}
```